# .htaccess Accept no php extension, but don't force it

Tags: php, .htaccess

I built a website, and now want to remove the .php off of the filenames. That said, I have a ton of code and forms, and when I put foo.php, it redirects to foo, and then removes all the POST data.

Is there a way that
example.com/foo.php **and**
example.com/foo
will go to the same place? In other words, accept if the user took off the .php, but don't redirect if it's there.

Thanks for all of the help!

Comment: are you running an Apache server?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove your redirect rule and enable `MultiViews` option to allow extension-less URLs:

```
Options +MultiViews
```